# how to create an xml file to store user details in jsp?

Tags: java, xml, jsp

I have a site which contains user specific data, that is not constant(i.e., a perticular user can have multiple addresses or phone nos. etc.).
So I was thinking of storing it in a separate XML file per user in the server/local storage rather than in the database; but the problem is I don't know how to do that.
Can you please help me to create an XML file from JSP and how to retrieve the data from that XML file in the future?

If there is any other way to achieve this rather than creating an XML file, please specify that too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out JAXB. Database would be the best option if you want to persist your info. Or cache it in your appropriate (application) scope.

Comment: the no. of data is not specific. i.e. a user can can 2 addresses, phone no.; another can have 5 addresses & phone nos.; another user can have no addresses and phone no. at all. In that case storing it in database tables would be hectic; as there is no limit on the no. of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use java-xml apis such as [SAX](http://www.saxproject.org/) and [jdom](http://www.jdom.org/).

or hight-weight databaese such as [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) and [hsql](http://hsqldb.org/) and [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/)

Comment: i was reading about SAX and jdom; but couldn't understand how to implement them with JSP.
U were also telling about using databases. So, can I use MySql?
Also in databases I know how to create tables and retrieve data. But here I need to store details of each and every user. So, will I have to create a table for each and every user to store their unique details. IF not, how can I implement?

Comment: one table for all users. column on table specifies user details. one column must be the user id i.e a unique identifier...

Comment: but here the no. of details differs from user to user. (ie. a user can can 2 addresses, phone no.; another can have 5 addresses & 5 phone nos.; another user can have no addresses and phone no. at all). In short the no. of columns is not constant.
I already have a table(register) for all users to store an id(unique), email, password,date of birth. What I'm asking is for the extra details to store that differs form user to user. ie.User specific data. much like facebook.

Comment: so you can create one table for addresses and one for phones and then join them. i suggest you to read some doc about relational database design.

Comment: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html may be usfull.

Comment: Ok, this is a good idea. but addresses and phone no. are not the only user specific data. There are many like, wishlist, previous orders, favorite items and many more... So u are suggesting to have different table for each of these. Isn't there more appropriate way to do this? I think creating a separate XML file for each user might help. ??? is it so.??

Comment: if u want to use database u should design a good relational model: one table for each entity and relation tables. but if u want to use xml files to store data, design should be different.